# Package Manager has died Caused by android.os.DeadObjectException

Tags: android, google-play

I stumbled upon an Exception sent by Crashlytics in my app. Client Android Version is 5.1.1.
I recieve the following Stack trace:

Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Package manager has died

```
android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo (ApplicationPackageManager.java:160)
com.google.android.gms.common.zzp.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.common.zzf.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzar.zzaib (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzay.run (Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:422)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbhc.run (Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

Caused by android.os.DeadObjectException

```
android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (Binder.java)
android.os.BinderProxy.transact (Binder.java:496)
android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.getPackageInfo (IPackageManager.java:2169)
android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo (ApplicationPackageManager.java:155)
com.google.android.gms.common.zzp.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.common.zzf.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzar.zzaib (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzay.run (Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:422)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbhc.run (Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

Backround Information:

Im developing an Firebase App with GPS functionality. Ive implemented the Google Location API in a Foreground Service and so far this error only occured with one client running the Foreground Service of my App intentionally for over 10 days.
In my Foreground Service Im not calling the Package Manager directly in any way.
The only hint I can give you is the last log I recieved from Crashlytics in the

```
@Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i)
    {
        CrashReporting.log("OnConnectionSuspended");
    }
```

Method of Google Api Class.

```
@Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult)
    {
        CrashReporting.report(new Exception("GPSBackgroundService, OnConnectionFailed"));
    }
```

did not log anything.

If you need any more Information please let me know and thank you in advance

Comment: Have you found the solution ?

Comment: @RavindMaurya I believe it was due to a Google Play Service Upgrade on one of my clients phone. Not 100 % sure though. However, I did not experience the same problem again after Google Play Service 12

Comment: Actually This problem was occuring due to com.adjust.sdk:adjust-android:4.11.0 , I have just updated it to 4.12 . Now It has been resolved now . Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Any leads for this crash. I am getting lots of crash in one pf my app. and it is affecting large user base. And Firebase showing mostly users are in foreground

Answer (score 1):

The android.os.DeadObjectException means that you link to something, that does not exist anymore.

And as far as I have found about this problem its hardware related problem